# Changing test name in python unittest using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, python-unittest

I have a question. Is it possible to change the name test in output, using python unittests?

For example, my test:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
from data.readData import Data
from actions.actions import Actions
from pages.notificationsPage import NotificationsPage

class NotificationsTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=Data.driver)
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        cls.driver.maximize_window()

    def test_order_confirmation(self):
        Actions.login(self, Data.email, Data.password)
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(Data.website + "Admin/Configuration/Message")
        notify = NotificationsPage(driver)
        notify.order_confirmation()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.close()
        cls.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

And my output:

[image: my test output screenshot]

I want to change the marked one test name to own string here, in this output, and also in result file in res.xml (I think it is the same value).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Just simply change the name of your tests method. Just Change:

```
    def test_order_confirmation(self):
```

to

```
def whatever_you_want_to_call_your_test(self):
```

Comment: Heh, well... yes. I know. My question is different: How to change test name to simple string? No ```test_order_confirmation``` but "Test order configuration".